# Elasticsearch HelathCheck failed : Unknown host

Tags: spring-boot-actuator, spring-data-elasticsearch, spring-boot-3, elasticsearch-8

An elasticsearch server version 8 is up with docker compose but the ElasticSearch health check failed when starting my springboot applcation,

I am working with Elastic Search 8 on Spring boot 3

the docker compose file :

```
version: "3.9"
services:

  ############ ELASTICSEARCH ############
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: es-container
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.10.2
    environment:
      - "xpack.security.enabled=false"
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
```

this is the outpout of http://localhost:9200

```
{
  "name" : "0e72b2bf938d",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "pqXHLJc-Tiu3rZ0OQT98qw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "8.10.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "6d20dd8ce62365be9b1aca96427de4622e970e9e",
    "build_date" : "2023-09-19T08:16:24.564900370Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "9.7.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.17.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

docker ps :

```
0e72b2bf938d   docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.10.2   "/bin/tini -- /usr/l…"   24 minutes ago   Up 24 minutes   0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9300->9300/tcp         es-container
```

This is my application-local.yaml config:

```
spring:
  elasticsearch:
    uris: http://localhost:9200
    socket-timeout: 5000
    connection-timeout: 5000
    consumer:
      group-id: local
```

When starting my app:

```
2023-09-29T11:23:29.803+02:00  WARN 11700 --- [)-10.205.124.82] d.e.ElasticsearchReactiveHealthIndicator : Elasticsearch health check failed

java.net.UnknownHostException: Hôte inconnu (http://localhost:9200)
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:933)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1543)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:852)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1532)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1384)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1305)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalAddressResolver.resolveRemoteAddress(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:666)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalAddressResolver.resolveRemoteAddress(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:637)
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool.processPendingRequest(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:472)
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool.lease(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:280)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.requestConnection(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:295)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.AbstractClientExchangeHandler.requestConnection(AbstractClientExchangeHandler.java:381)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.start(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:130)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.execute(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:116)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalHttpAsyncClient.execute(InternalHttpAsyncClient.java:138)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.lambda$performRequestAsync$0(RestClient.java:393)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.Cancellable$RequestCancellable.runIfNotCancelled(Cancellable.java:90)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequestAsync(RestClient.java:391)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequestAsync(RestClient.java:378)
    at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.performRequestAsync(RestClientTransport.java:163)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ReactiveElasticsearchClusterClient.health(ReactiveElasticsearchClusterClient.java:50)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ReactiveElasticsearchClusterClient.health(ReactiveElasticsearchClusterClient.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchReactiveHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(ElasticsearchReactiveHealthIndicator.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractReactiveHealthIndicator.health(AbstractReactiveHealthIndicator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.ReactiveHealthIndicator.getHealth(ReactiveHealthIndicator.java:42)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthEndpointConfiguration$AdaptedReactiveHealthContributors$1.getHealth(HealthEndpointConfiguration.java:160)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:41)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getLoggedHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:172)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getAggregateContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:156)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:110)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:66)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:281)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:124)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:97)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:814)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1472)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1310)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1405)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

how can i fix the health indicator of elasticsearch ?

Comment: Problem solved: have to configure RestClientBuilder